# Qt C++ Graphics View get Mouse Position on Click

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I'm pretty new to Qt.
I have a QGraphicsView in my main window and I'd like to get the position of the mouse (0,0 being the top left corner of the graphics view object) when clicked inside of the graphics view object.

Generally speaking, how would I approach this task? Does a QGraphicsView have a Clicked() signal? I've also read about something called EventFilter. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Unfortunatelly `QGraphicsView` doesn't have `clicked` signal. You can obtain the mouse position with a call to [QMouseEvent::pos](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html#pos) in a reimplementation of [QGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#mouseReleaseEvent). Then you can emit your own `clicked` signal and pass the mouse position as an argument.

Comment: Thanks, how would I reimplement mouseReleaseEvent function of QGraphicsView?

Comment: I am on the go now and I will write a detailed answer later.